# Testing activesync with android virtual devices

Tags: android, activesync

I am trying to setup a android virtual device to test syncing with an `activesync-server`.
I followed these [steps:](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-activesync-virtual-android-device)

The problem is that syncing is not working at all, but there are no errors like connection errors ...

IMO the problem is that the virtual device only has a private IP, so the server never can send anything to it?

So I probably need some kind of forwarding, like [here:](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#redirection)

But I am not sure if that’s correct and I am also not sure which ports should be forwarded.

Here is the logcat, when I want to sync:

```
W/InputMethodManagerService(  148): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41302038 attribute=null
I/Choreographer(  274): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm(  477): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 6% free 8392K/8903K, paused 15ms+7ms, total 527ms
D/dalvikvm(  274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 360K, 11% free 9493K/10567K, paused 29ms+48ms, total 142ms
I/EAS ContactsSyncAdapterService(  477): Contact sync requested for test@example.com
D/dalvikvm(  148): GREF has increased to 601
D/dalvikvm(  477): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
I/Choreographer(  274): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm(  477): GC_EXPLICIT freed 333K, 7% free 8355K/8903K, paused 78ms+32ms, total 1269ms
I/EAS EmailSyncAdapterService(  477): performSync
I/EAS EmailSyncAdapterService(  477): Mail sync requested for test@example.com
D/dalvikvm(  460): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
D/dalvikvm(  460): GC_EXPLICIT freed 216K, 5% free 8483K/8839K, paused 145ms+94ms, total 914ms
D/dalvikvm(  148): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
D/dalvikvm(  148): GC_EXPLICIT freed 510K, 7% free 11338K/12167K, paused 8ms+35ms, total 323ms
D/dalvikvm(  274): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 11% free 9486K/10567K, paused 25ms+28ms, total 125ms
E/Inbox[test@example.com](  477): Uncaught exception in EasSyncServicejava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=32; index=32
E/Inbox[test@example.com](  477): Sync ended due to an exception.
D/dalvikvm(  477): GC_CONCURRENT freed 376K, 6% free 8420K/8903K, paused 5ms+18ms, total 66ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem with your networking setup. It looks like you have an error in your Sync code, that is causing the process to stop:

E/Inboxtest@example.com: Uncaught exception in EasSyncServicejava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=32; index=32
E/Inboxtest@example.com: Sync ended due to an exception.

>

Wrap this code in a try/catch block to understand what is happening better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although I couldnt solve my problem with your answer, I found out that the problem was a configuration problem with my zpush protocol I was using. One final question though, I can not add an ActiveSync Account on a Android 4.2 device. I can only add Google accounts. Did Google disable support for ActiveSync on Android 4.2

Comment: Yes, I think they did disable ActiveSync recently in GMail.  I am not thinking this would be on an API level though - but not my area of expertise.  http://www.theverge.com/2012/12/14/3767626/google-dropping-google-sync-exchange-support-for-gmail-calendar-and